# Write a program in Prolog to implement vanish(R,L,N) where R denotes the element whose all occurrences has to be remove from list L to obtain list N

Tags: prolog

Write a program in Prolog to implement vanish(R,L,N) where R denotes
the element whose all occurrences has to be remove from list L to obtain
list N.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a boot camp Prolog exercise; some effort is required.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
vanish(_,[],[]).
vanish(E,[E|Ls],N) :- vanish(E,Ls,N).
vanish(E,[L|Ls],[L|Ns]) :- L\=E, vanish(E,Ls,Ns).
```